# squid and ftp connections

Tags: ftp, squid

i have a squid proxy server for both, http and ftp connections, i'm trying to use filezilla to open a ftp, but it always fail with an error saying:

```
Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Response:   Proxy reply: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Error:  Proxy handshake failed: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

i sniff the traffic, and, filezilla is trying to connect to a different port and the proxy denied it
look, this is a portion of the sniff result

```
CONNECT 201.150.36.227:61179 HTTP/1.1
Host: 201.150.36.227:61179
User-Agent: FileZilla
```

everytime is a different port, so, no way i can allow it in the squid, also, i set the filezilla to use a active connection, same result, passive connection, same result again, so, i'm out of bullets, and i need your help, maybe a setting in the filezilla or in the squid can do the job, so, give a hand here

this is the full log of the filezilla

```
    Status: Connecting to uhma.mx through proxy
Status: Connecting to 172.19.216.13:3128...
Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Response:   Proxy reply: HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (a3 FTP CUATRO) [201.150.36.227]
Command:    USER uhmamx
Response:   331 Password required for uhmamx
Command:    PASS *******
Response:   230 User uhmamx logged in
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (201,150,36,227,238,251).
Command:    MLSD
Status: Connecting to 172.19.216.13:3128...
Status: Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
Response:   Proxy reply: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Error:  Proxy handshake failed: ECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: is it possible to allow a port range in squid??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added a port range to the squid.conf, and configured the filezilla to restrict the port range it is going to use

```
acl SSL_ports port 50000-50010
```

now, it is working just fine.

thanks